# Replace of XKeycodeToKeysym

Tags: c, linux, x11

When I try to build my code with the X11 headers in Ubuntu 12.04

```
    case KeyPress:
        xcommon_update_server_time( event.xkey.time );
        /* if( event.xkey.state & ShiftMask ) arg |= I_SHIFT; */
        /* this alternate approach allows handling of keys like '<' and '>' -- mrallen */
        if( event.xkey.state & ShiftMask ) {
            mykey = XKeycodeToKeysym( display, event.xkey.keycode, 1 );
        } else {
            mykey = XKeycodeToKeysym( display, event.xkey.keycode, 0 );
        }
```

What is the expected result?
Compiles.

What happens instead?

```
warning: 'XKeycodeToKeysym' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:1695) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
```

As a result of https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5349 XKeycodeToKeysym is now properly marked as being deprecated.

How to fix my code for warning free and correct build?

Thanks

Comment: Comment #5 on the bug page you linked mentions `XkbKeycodeToKeysym`, wouldn't that do what you want?

Comment: Eric,
My question

Adding:

#include <X11/XKBlib.h>

and changing 

XKeycodeToKeysym( display, event.xkey.keycode, 1 );
with
XkbKeycodeToKeysym(g_display, e.xkey.keycode, 1, 0);

and

XKeycodeToKeysym( display, event.xkey.keycode, 0 );
with:
XkbKeycodeToKeysym(g_display, e.xkey.keycode, 0, 0);

is correct solution?

Comment: I believe you need to swap the last two parameters. I have no experience with X11 programming, but I gather from this page http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XkbKeyAction.3.html that `idx = group_index * key_width + shift_level`, which matches with the 3rd parameter (index) in your old code corresponding to the shift-key.

Comment: Look @documentation and changelog, deprecated stuff is not evil, it is just being replaced in favor of newer code. SCM search will show you version in which it got deprecated and why.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Provided `XKB` is available then the simplest replacement for `XKeycodeToKeysym` is:

```
#include <X11/XKBlib.h>
/* which declares:
     KeySym XkbKeycodeToKeysym(Display *dpy, KeyCode kc,
                               unsigned int group, unsigned int level); */
```

... and then the original question's code could become:

```
    mykey = XkbKeycodeToKeysym( display, event.xkey.keycode, 
                                0, event.xkey.state & ShiftMask ? 1 : 0);
```

notes:

- this [chromium bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117210) discusses both the `XGetKeyboardMapping` and the `XKB` replacement solutions.
- [XkbKeyCodeToKeysym](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XkbKeycodeToKeysym.3.html) man page on X.org

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It takes care of ShiftMask as well, which saves a lot of headache. Only why does it say "provided XKB is available"? Does it happen that X11 comes without XKB?

Comment: I am also curious @AlwaysLearning , is it possible for XKB to not be there ? In all the X11 systems I tested it was there.

Comment: XKB isn't there in the Ubuntu 16 tightvnc server.

Answer (score 7):

Show you an example and you can do the same on your source.

Replace

`keysym = XKeycodeToKeysym(dpy,xe->xkey.keycode,0)`

with

```
{
    int keysyms_per_keycode_return;
    KeySym *keysym = XGetKeyboardMapping(dpy,
        xe->xkey.keycode,
        1,
        &keysyms_per_keycode_return);

    /* do something with keysym[0] */

    XFree(keysym);
}
```

Not forgetting to free the return value.

Answer (score 0):

XStringToKeysym() can be used for this.
Convert your key-code value to a hexadecimal string, with added "0x" prefix, and it will return the correct key-sym value.

```
// 0xffbe = F1 
KeySym keysym = XStringToKeysym("0xffbe");
```